# Value of a variable changes when i pass it to a function

Tags: c

I bumped into an issue today while debugging my program.

I am trying to pass an integer variable to a function in the same program. When the function receives the value, somehow the value is different in the receiving variable inside the function and I just cannot find out why.

Below is line where the function is called.

```
prefetch_miss(addr,pref_m,sbuff,0,evict_row, SB);
```

Below is starting 3 lines of the receiving function.

```
void prefetch_miss(int address, int m, s **sbuff, int next, int r, cache *b) {

int index_value=0, tag_value=0;
address = address + 1;
```

Please note that addr is a global variable. In debug, I can see the value of addr right before function call as 33558587. Inside the function, the value of address is 33558569.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you narrow your code down to a [small self-contained program](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Check the access to the object that is just before your variable in memory, you could have a buffer overflow and your object is modified during the overflow.

Comment: @KeithThompson I tried writing a simple program with similar logic but that is working fine.

Comment: Too simple, then. Start with your existing code and discard chunks of it until the problem goes away, then go back one step. (A source control system helps.)

Comment: The actual program has the same flow as the below program, except that I read addr from a file.                                                  #include<stdio.h>
int addr = 0;
void prefetch(int);

int main() {
addr = 33558587;
write();
}

write() {
prefetch_miss(addr);
}

prefetch_miss(int address) {
address = address + 1;
}

Comment: oops..sry for the above comment. I thought code would get formatted in comments too.

Comment: @ouah - the value of addr after the function return is still 33558587. But the value that is received in address is different.

Comment: I noticed that the function receives correct value in address, but in the statement "address = address + 1", 1 gets added to 33558569 resulting in the value of 33558570 in addr.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some sort of array defined before your global variable and you are overwriting it beyond the allocation of the array size and thereby the changing the value of the variable address. BTW if address is a global variable why do you need to pass it to a routine? Global variable are visible to all routines.

Comment: The way I have coded mandates passing the global variable. I have overcome the problem by assigning the value to another local and passing it. However I still do not understand why the problem is occurring. Well I guess I should have explained the problem with more clarity. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Copying the value to the local variable can solve your problem, but I would recommend you to fix the actual problem why the global variable is getting modified. I had faced a similar problem once, the global variable was getting overwritten when a array which was defined before the global variable was being overflowed and it was causing my program to crash. I suggest you to run your program through a debugger and try to see at each step if the variable is being modified.